# How to reference the PHP SDK for Zoho API Version 2

Tags: php, api, sdk, zoho

I am attempting to use the PHP SDK to access the Zoho API. I have successfully installed the SDK using composer as per the instructions, and it sits in the /vendor folder on my web site.

So if I create a PHP page, which part do I need to reference with require or include or whatever to give my PHP page access to the SDK code.

There are a lot of examples with small code snippets but none which show a complete page. Can anybody help?